# How to find the scroll position of a particular element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This might seem like a basic question but for some reason things like `document.body.offsetTop`, `window.scrollY`, `window.scrollTop`, `document.body.scrollTop`, `window.pageYOffset`, and the like are returning `0` or `undefined` regardless of where I've scrolled on the page. A couple other details, this is on mobile Safari which I'm running on the XCode simulator and inspecting with the Safari developer tool. My code, which uses `document.pageYOffset`, works properly on desktop browsers. The only other limitation is that I can't use jQuery. All the other times this question has been asked, the answer uses things like `window.scrollY` or something like that which just don't work here. Are there alternate ways to get a page's (or a particular element's) scroll position? (Edit: relative to the viewport)

Comment: Scroll position _relative to what_? The viewport? A container element? You need to provide code and/or clarify your question.

Comment: @AndréDion The viewport

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that selecting the element and then calling `getBoundingClientRect` works for this. So for example: `let containerPosition = document.getElementById('select-unauthenticated-home-container').getBoundingClientRect().top;` And then you can add your behavior based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery , [$("selector").scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [$("selector").scrollLeft](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) .

```
var scrolltop = $("selector").scrollTop();
var scrollleft = $("selector").scrollLeft();
```

Comment: OP stated that he cannot use jQuery.

Comment: @AndréDion what is OP !?

Comment: Original Poster (the person who asked the question).

Comment: @AndréDion yeh, tanx.